# Focus engine might keep alive dismissed views

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I would like to have your opinion about a strange behavior I have found on tvOS.

## Description

There are two ways to focus an item with a Apple TV remote : using a swipe gesture or touching one of the side (right, left, top or bottom) of the remote's pad.

If we use the first option to focus an item right before dismissing the current view controller, all the views of the view controller and the view controller it-self are released.

But, if we use the second option to focus an item right before dismissing the current view controller, all the focusable views of this view controller seem to be kept into the memory. The presented view controller is released; not its focusable views.

The focusable views will be only released if we touch (not swipe) again the pad of the remote. This solution works regardless of where we are in the application.

## Example

```
/// A custom focusable view
class FocusableView : UIView {

    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool { return true }

    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
            backgroundColor = .lightGray
        } else if context.nextFocusedView == self {
            backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("FocusableView deinit")
    }
}

/// The presented view controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var leftView: FocusableView!

    @IBOutlet private var rightView: FocusableView!

    deinit {
        print("ViewController deinit")
    }
}
```

`ViewController` is presented if we select the `GO` button of a first simple view controller, like so :
[image: storyboard]

If we present `ViewController`, we focus its right item with a **swipe** and then we dismiss `ViewController` with the Menu button, the console prints :

```
ViewController deinit
FocusableView deinit
FocusableView deinit
```

Now, if we present `ViewController`, we focus its right item with a **touch** on the right side of the remote and then we dismiss `ViewController` with Menu button, the console only prints :

```
ViewController deinit
```

The focusable views will be only released if we touch again the remote.

## Memory graph

If we take a look at the memory graph when using a touch to focus an item, the focusable items seems to be retained by a strong reference of a mysterious `_UIFocusMapSnapshot`:
[image: memory graph]

It might be really disturbing if one the view has a `AVPlayerLayer`, the sound of player goes on while its view is dismissed.

## UPDATE

Apple has lately answered to my bug report : this is a UIKit bug fixed since tvOS 11 beta

Comment: Very nice analysis, how did you make this graph?:) I suggest you file a bug to Apple about that, an meanwhile bypass this in `deinit` of view controller and stop all AVPlayers.

Comment: This is a Xcode 8 's new feature : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-DontLinkElementID_1.

I sent a bug report to Apple. But Apple is not really eloquent.